# How to capture Ultrasonic Cross-Device Tracking signals?

Tags: smart-home, communication, data-transfer, tracking-devices, sound

I found out that many devices as PCs, TVs, cellphones and more can use a technology called **ultrasonic cross-device tracking**. This means that there are ultrahigh sound frequencies which propagate from device's speakers and are received by nearby microphone embedded in other devices. This allows to transfer data.

Is there a way to capture these signals? Is there some app maybe that listens to Ultrasonic frequencies and let's me know what type of info is been transfered?

Comment: You have speaker and microphone interchanged in your question above.   I think it is possible to find apps that can cut out certain frequency ranges. So, if you were to take your phone near the TV and have the app listen to the TV and make a recording while it cuts out say, everything below 15kHz, you'll have a file. Then, you'd have to shift that file many octaves down and you'll hear something.  If all else fails, call one of these guys. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89vNqmZYgZE   !!

Comment: Yeah you are right I mixed them

Comment: you answered your first question before you asked it

Comment: @jsotola what do you mean?

Comment: in the second paragraph, you asked `Is there a way to capture these signals?` ... in the first paragraph, you said `... received by nearby microphone embedded in other devices` .... so, the answer is `yes`

Comment: If you don't have an answer or don't know how to do it, you don't need to waste people's time

Comment: @FedericoGentile then ask `how to capture signals?` ... anyway, you also answered that question in the first paragraph ... use your PC's microphone ... as for the app,  run a program such as Audacity